# 400 error message when implementing sign up with facebook from the firebase SDK in my web App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, facebook, google-signin

I am trying to setup sign in with facebook but i get the error
"index.ts:136     POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=AIzaSyDI8GEU9X64aK_u2GOrKIRj8xDR8SseBIQ 400"

I enabled the method in firebase adding the app id and the app secret
in the facebook console
I added the redirect domain
and fake filled out some other stuff

I dont know whats missing or what this error tells me. googlin for it gives me nothing

[image: firebase enabled facebook sign in]

[image: facebook console with some faux entries]

[image: error message]

[image: the redirect]